# Problem running a python pipeline in jenkins

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

*It is showing this error:*
    process apparently never started in /Users/sannan/.jenkins/workspace/Ci-Cd 
    Python@tmp/durable-177ff2f5
    (running Jenkins temporarily with - 
    Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true might make the 
    problem clearer)

*And in console output:*

```
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
Jenkins does not seem to be running inside a container
$ docker run -t -d -u 501:20 -w "/Users/sannan/.jenkins/workspace/Ci-Cd Python" -v 
"/Users/sannan/.jenkins/workspace/Ci-Cd Python:/Users/sannan/.jenkins/workspace/Ci-Cd 
Python:rw,z" -v "/Users/sannan/.jenkins/workspace/Ci-Cd 
Python@tmp:/Users/sannan/.jenkins/workspace/Ci-Cd Python@tmp:rw,z" -e ******** -e ******** - 
e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e 
******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** 
-e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e 
******** -e ******** -e ******** cdrx/pyinstaller-linux:python2 cat
$ docker top f1bd0d8a963d6250048ca2ee86020034ef6b42a6007d97ba95c9bdc60f5913bc -eo pid,comm
ERROR: The container started but didn't run the expected command. Please double check your 
ENTRYPOINT does execute the command passed as docker run argument, as required by official 
docker images (see https://github.com/docker-library/official-images#consistency for 
entrypoint consistency requirements).
Alternatively you can force image entrypoint to be disabled by adding option `-- 
entrypoint=''`.
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
 process apparently never started in /Users/sannan/.jenkins/workspace/Ci-Cd 
 Python@tmp/durable-177ff2f5
(running Jenkins temporarily with - 
Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true might make the 
problem clearer)
[Pipeline] }
$ docker stop --time=1 f1bd0d8a963d6250048ca2ee86020034ef6b42a6007d97ba95c9bdc60f5913bc
$ docker rm -f f1bd0d8a963d6250048ca2ee86020034ef6b42a6007d97ba95c9bdc60f5913bc
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code -2
Finished: FAILURE
```